# why every request is being processed as a ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have started with a new application development using rails 4.0. But I dont konw why every request is being processed as ajax request. for example suppose I have one link like this :

```
 =link_to  "View detail", product_detail_path(:seo_name => vp.product.seo_name, :vp_id => vp.id), :class => "btn btn-default"
```

which takes me to the product detail path, and I have this code in my controller for the same link

```
def show
  @product = Product.find_by_seo_name(params[:id]) #here in params[:id] you will get seo_name of product        
  @other_variants = @product.variant_products.where("variant_products.id NOT IN (?)", @variant.id)
end
```

but when I hit the same link, it takes me to the product show page, but it is processed as ajax request. when I right click to inspect element I can see this line on console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/products/product-1-tb002?vp_id=71
```

same case is with my other links as well those which are processed as ajax links and those which are processed as html requests. can't understand what is the issue!

you can see in a below screenshot I have clicked on "view detail" button, which take me to the show page of my product. that link does not contain "remote => true". and I think still it gets processed as ajax request.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBQpy.jpg
```

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/products/product-1-tb002?vp_id=71 does not mean it's an ajax request.

Comment: then what could be the problem :(

Comment: you don't mention an actual problem. edit your post to say what you think is supposed to happen and make it clear what isn't happening. The question you posted doesn't actually state what problem you're having. If something were being processed as ajax the page would not redirect / refresh.

Comment: Yes exactly, my page is not getting refreshed. I have lots of jquery written in my common javascript file and i have included it in my application.js file. but the thing is that when i am clicking on the same link as i a have mentioned above, it takes me to that respective page but my javascript is not getting executed and when i refresh the same page then only it gets executed. and i have written this code inside document.ready function

Comment: generally when page is refreshed , browser console does not show us that this particular request is being processed(i.e. GET localhost:3000/products/product-1-tb002?vp_id=71). As per my understanding, it only shows when ajax request is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with turbolinks. Disable remove/turbolinks and you should see the specified/expected behavior.